# How to use more than one check in a wait_for on discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a game on discord.py that allows you to choose more than one option. Each option does something different and it sends out a list of what to do at the beginning. it is having issues allowing this and is saying that "arg is a required argument that is missing" when I input the command into discord. is doing what I want even remotely possible? here is my code:

```
@client.command(description="The Sword Game", name="Sword Sim", aliases=["sg", "sword", "sword-game"])
async def SwordGame(ctx, arg):
    embed = discord.Embed(
    title='Sword Simulator Game',
    Description="The Sword Simulator game by MrPenguin280",
    color=discord.Color.dark_red()
 )
    choiceslist='''
1 = Battle
2 = Check Sword Stats
3 = Check Player Stats
4 = Heal
5 = Power up Magic
6 = XP farm
7 = Leave Sim
'''
    embed.add_field(name='Choices:\n', value=choiceslist)
    embed.add_field(name='What do you choose?', value="Type it below")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    def check(m):
        return m.content == "1"
        return m.content == "7"
        return m.content == "2"
        return m.content == "3"
        return m.content == "4"
        return m.content == "5"
        return m.content == "6"
    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)
    if msg == "1":
        await ctx.send("You picked to battle")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions end as soon as a return is reached, doesn't matter if the value is False or None, the check is gonna return always the first statement, here's the fixed code

```py
def check(message):
    return message.content in ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```